# Class of economics

Tags: word-usage, word-request, difference, vocabulary

Is it okay to say "class of economics"? I am in high school and have a extended curriculum in a subject called economics or business basics. How can I say this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an unnecessarily long answer, but here we go:
If you're referring to the actual class itself, you can call it "Economics" or even just "Econ" (an abbreviation), depending on whom you're talking to. "Econ" is more casual, like if you're talking to a friend. Here's an example.

- I take Econ at 1. (I am in the Economics classroom at one in the afternoon.)

Note that with many other classes, you can either say "### class" or just "###", like "I'm going to math class" or "I'm going to math." Judging by ear, though, "I'm going to economics class" seems weird, so just stick with "I'm going to economics."
Note also that it seems weird to say, "I take math class at 1." "I take math at 1" just sounds better, or at least more natural to me. (By the way, class names should be capitalized if they're a specific class, like "I take Algebra I/Basic Economics at 1.")

Finally, a reminder/nitpick that you use "an" instead of "a" before words that start with vowels. You wrote, "[I] have a extended curriculum," but that "an" should change to an "a" to make it flow better: "I have an extended curriculum."

Answer (score 1):

A *class of economics* would normally be considered a ***type*** *of economics* or ***category*** *of economics*.

It would be considered in the same light as the third sense of *class* as provided by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class):

> **3** : a group, set, or kind sharing common attributes

In other words:

> What class of economics theory did you apply when analyizing the sudden downturn in today's market?

---

If you're talking about a classroom, what you would normally say is:

> I have to attend my *economics class* this morning.